# Geospacial search - Entity Framework Core / PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table storing some events locations and a class mapped to it with ef core:

```
public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Column(TypeName = "geography (point)")]
        public Point Location { get; set; }

        public string? Address { get; set; }

        public string? City { get; set; }

        public string? Region { get; set; }

        public string? Country { get; set; }

        public Post Post { get; set; }

        public int PostId { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Problem**
The Location class has a 1 - 1 relationship with the Post.
Now, given an input of latitude and longitude and radius of **X km**, I want to be able to get all posts from the database within that radius. i.e I want to perform a geospacial query.

I found a solution but it involves performing some plain SQL queries which I try to avoid at all costs.
How would I perform it with LINQ?

Comment: What is the meaning of `radius X km` you mentioned here, it is not field, and what is the structure of your `Post` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution comes from  [Postgis](https://postgis.net/). It adds support for geographic objects allowing location queries to be run in SQL. It has to be installed on the DB side. For the server-side, the following [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite/3.1.0?_src=template) has to be installed.

The relevant method that can perform a geospatial query is called ".IsWithinDistance".
The latitude, longitude have to be passed as a Point, and the radius. That will return all records within the specified range.

Example:

```
posts = await Context.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Location)                
        .Where(p => p.Location.Location.IsWithinDistance(location, radius * 1000) 
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```